# How operating system exporting window screen to projector?

Tags: operating-systems, hdmi, vga, projector

I have some queries regarding how operating system exporting window screen to projector to display on some screen?.

For Example:

1. When we open power point presentation on our laptop/desktop and connect VGA/HDMI port on our system and exporting that presentation screen to project to display.
2. Suppose, In my system currently running one text editor and one power point presentation, but i want to sent the projector out put only power point presentation, more over, if i type something on text editor, it should not visible on projector screen

For this queries if you any code example or theory kindly share with me. So that i can get into the first step to solve the problem.

For my understanding:

May be operating system share the screen of the process to particular port VGA/HDMI.

If operating system sharing the screen based on the process means, if i open two power point presentation and i want to share only one presentation among them means how can i control it.

If i want to control only few process screen want to share to the projector rest i want to control means how to achieve that, which language give more control over my requirement (Example: java, python, etc.,).

If question is not clear kindly comment below, will try to explain more. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Most probably when you connect a projector to your machine. Presentation is visible on Projector Screen. While you desktop is on Laptop/Desktop. So if you want to do something Move that application to Projector Screen.

Comment: Can i control only some of application screen only send to projector screen?

Comment: No Idea. But If You Fill the Projector Screen with "some of application screen only" then it would be like you want.

Comment: But the requirement is i will share power point presentation screen to projector screen, at same time i want to work on text editor on my laptop/desktop with out sharing that screen to projector screen. But the way you told, i can't right, because when i bring my text editor to front for editing it will project or projector screen right.

Comment: Press Windows+P and Select Extend.

Comment: What about in mac...

Comment: No Idea didn't use. but you can surely search the internet for 'projector mode extend duplicate mac os x'